# Scheduled Python task no more executing

Tags: python, windows-11, scheduled-tasks

I have a backup task written in Python 3.7.1 and I scheduled it for automatic daily execution via the Task Scheduler.

Until recently, it worked seamlessly, and I could see its activity on a console. But now, without me changing any related setting, the script is no more executed, and I don't see a console anymore. Though the Task Scheduler reports successful execution at the scheduled time.

When launched manually, the script still runs as should.

The only reason I could think of is a change of behavior after a Windows 11 update. But I have no clue how to troubleshoot and fix this.

Comment: What do you see in the Events? It probably is a rights issue.

Comment: @tukan: I don't know where to look, there are trillion lines in the Event Viewer. By the way, I did not change any rights myself.

Comment: Try filtering out by your script.  Well windows updates have tendency changing what they think is the best, no surprise there.

Comment: Have you tried to recreate the task under a different name after the update?

Comment: @tukan: I don't know how to "filter" nor where. There are too many choices. Could you be more specific ?

Comment: @GChuf: I recreated a scheduled task. When I launch it manually from the Task Scheduler, it goes to the Running state forever (but nothing happens). The script still works outside the Task Scheduler.

Comment: I see. Event viewer is the first place to go, as already mentioned. - when you execute your task manually you'll know exactly the time of the execution. Check if there are any errors. Another thing you can do is to include some logging inside your script, to see if it actually executed.

Comment: @GChuf: I see that the task is not executed because no copy is performed. But what is the purpose of knowing the time of execution if I launch manually ? Telling me Event Viewer is not helpful, this is a labyrinth.

Comment: The purpose is to find the error in the event log easier. The copy not being performed also doesn't necessarily mean that the script didn't execute - maybe it did, but it failed.

Comment: You don't use MS GUI (you would need to use third party soft) you use powershell e.g. `Get-WinEvent | ? { $_.TaskDisplayName -eq "Python script" }`

Comment: @tukan: The instance name passed was not recognized as valid
by a WMI data provider.

Comment: The instance name is not same as task display name, are you sure you gave it the right name?

Comment: @tukan: of course, I tried everything.

Comment: @tukan: I browsed the unfiltered list of events. There is nothing reported around the scheduled launch time.

Comment: The PowerShell Get-WinEvent comand is even worse than the EventViewer !

Comment: Hmm hard to help.  You could try to see if there is any error generated `Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Error;`.  If that does not help you can try to run the task with sysmon (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon) started to see what is actually going on.

Comment: @tukan: there is only one error in EventLog today, unrelated to the scheduled task :-(

Comment: @tukan: After checking the task history, I see that it is effectively launched (with OpenWith.exe) and completes immediately.

Comment: Please add to your post screenshots of the task's definition screens in Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved myself, by explicitly specifying for the action the full path to the Python command and supplying the script as an argument.

Previously, just specifying the script was enough. Interestingly, the end time remains equal to the start time.

I have the solution, but unfortunately I'll never know what has changed.

Comment: That is weird.  That should have give an error along these lines "executable not found".  Even weirder is that manually it ran.

Comment: @tukan: I agree with you and have no explanation.

Comment: Is the explanation that a scheduled task has no PATH, so an executable process needs to have its path be specified fully?

Comment: @harrymc that makes sense.  The issue is that it worked before the updates and "something" changed.

Comment: @harrymc: no, I did not change that. By the way, the Task Scheduler warns when the path is not found, even before execution !

Comment: If you have changed nothing when it happened, it seems that something was wrong before and was fixed, perhaps with a Windows Update. The fact that it worked before was the aberration, the way it's working now is how it has been since always.

Comment: @harrymc: isn't it the converse ? A wrong change in the behavior of OpenWith.exe ?

Comment: OpenWith.exe does not relate to scheduled tasks.

Comment: @harrymc: except that the Task Scheduler said in the task history "launched with OpenWith.exe".

Comment: I don't know how this works internally in Windows, it's possible that OpenWith.exe has an undocumented call to find which application is supposed to execute a given file (just a theory).

Comment: I recommend to read [What must be taken into account on executing a batch file as scheduled task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41821620/3074564) and [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) I could tell you perhaps what was the reason that the scheduled task worked a long time and required now fully qualified file names, but you kept secret your task properties and your __system__ and __user__ environment variables `Path` as well as `PYTHONPATH` (for Python modules).

Comment: @Mofi: The task was directly referring to the .py file, with full path. And I did not specify anything myself in the environment variables, everything as by default at installation.

Comment: There was not `python.exe` with its fully qualified file name enclosed in `"` specified as __program/script__ to run with the fully qualified file name of the `.py` file as __optional argument__ also enclosed in `"` with __Start in__ defined with the fully qualified folder path of the folder never enclosed in `"` which should be used as current working directory?

Comment: I wonder that this worked ever because of the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) or [CreateProcessAsUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) called by the Windows task scheduler executable requires an executable to be defined as application to run with its full path except the executable is in `%SystemRoot%\System32`. A `.py` file is not an executable. It is just a script file (text file).

Comment: @Mofi: worked daily for three years.